# Azure Iot hub Device vs. Service SDK for getting desired properties from Device twin?

Tags: java, azure, gradle, iot, azure-iot-hub

This gives a paragraph summary of the *service* vs *device* sdk:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks

Hi, I have two repositories or projects I'm working on, one is using the Azure Iot Hub *Service* SDK (documentation API for java here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.service?view=azure-java-stable), which makes it very easy to get the DeviceTwin desired properties. I just need a `DeviceTwinDevice` object and then I call `getDesiredProperties()` on it. This all comes from the dependency:

```
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot', name: 'iot-service-client', version: '1.16.0'
```

**Now**, I am working on another repo, where I have to read a specific property from the Device twin, but that project is using the Azure Iot Hub *Device* SDK (documentation API for Java here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device?view=azure-java-stable), and it works a little different. It looks like they use a `DeviceClient` object to connect the Iot hub and such. I don't see any methods for retrieving the desired properties for the DeviceTwin other than a `getDeviceTwin()` method, but it is a void method and returns nothing? The dependency for this is

```
 compile(group: 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot', name: 'iot-device-client', version: '1.19.1')
```

For those of you who haven't seen these "properties" before, it's just JSON located on the Azure Portal website:
[image]

Is there an easy way to grab these properties with the *device* sdk or must I drag the dependency in Gradle for the *service* sdk and do it that way? It seems redundant. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDeviceTwin()` method in the Device SDK in Java works a little different from other languages. There is a really good sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/device/iot-device-samples/device-twin-sample/src/main/java/samples/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/DeviceTwinSample.java#L219). The magic happens a few lines about calling `getDeviceTwin()`, where you first define what properties you want to register a callback for. The samples below are all from the above link:

```java
System.out.println("Subscribe to Desired properties on device Twin...");
Map<Property, Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>> desiredProperties = new HashMap<Property, Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>>()
{
  {
    put(new Property("HomeTemp(F)", null), new Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>(new onHomeTempChange(), null));
    put(new Property("LivingRoomLights", null), new Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>(new onProperty(), null));
    put(new Property("BedroomRoomLights", null), new Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>(new onProperty(), null));
    put(new Property("HomeSecurityCamera", null), new Pair<TwinPropertyCallBack, Object>(new onCameraActivity(), null));
  }
};

client.subscribeToTwinDesiredProperties(desiredProperties);

System.out.println("Get device Twin...");
client.getDeviceTwin(); // Will trigger the callbacks.
```

Handling the received property is then done in the callback, for example:

```java
protected static class onProperty implements TwinPropertyCallBack
{
  @Override
  public void TwinPropertyCallBack(Property property, Object context)
  {
    System.out.println(
      "onProperty callback for " + (property.getIsReported()?"reported": "desired") +
      " property " + property.getKey() +
      " to " + property.getValue() +
      ", Properties version:" + property.getVersion());
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this DeviceTwinCallback act exactly as a Callback function in Javascript? Like the function is asynchronous and will "go" and only when it it is finished, then it will return and whatever the function you passed as the callback will THEN, and only then, be called? What if my Property (i.e. like "HomeTemp(F)" that you set above) doesn't change? will it just be returned automatically? I have some properties that are already inn the DeviceTwin and I just need to read that do not change... would this DeviceTwinCallback still work fine?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your answer. The callback function will only run when
1. The value is changed on the cloud side
2. You call `client.getDeviceTwin()` explicitly
So if you set the callback and subscribe to the property, it will not be fired until it changes. (again, unless you call `client.getDeviceTwin()` explicitly)
It's also good to mention that most devices start by booting up, connecting and retrieving their desired properties before doing much else.

Comment: Hi, based off what you showed me there, I'm still having trouble getting a specific property from the Callback functions. I saved one of the properties that I needed to read from device twin using "property.getValue()" from the CallbackHandler, but I need this value to be passed in as an argument for another function in my code, and that other function runs BEFORE this Callbackhandler returns the data I need. How can  I remedy this?. Is "null" always passed in for their initial state  for the desired properties Map? @Matthijs van der Veer